# How do I test for modelling error in the second data set?

Tags: normal-distribution, modeling

I have one set of experimental data set contains 669 samples and it describes  laminar flame speed by using three variables: pressure, temperature and equivalence ratio. This contains 12 different combinations of temperature and pressure (some cases contain just 9 data samples). I then create another set of data set, which is a simulation based upon the first set. I simulate every each combination with an additional 500 hundred simulations to extrapolate the data by a small fractional amount beyond the observed data range. The distribution of the data in the second set has a normal distribution of the standard deviation from the mean.

I'm not an expert in statistics and I don't know how should I describe the simulation and the modeling data.

I would be glad if someone could indicate the right way.

@update 9.03.2017-12:18

Whole analysis is for creating a model which describes the laminar burning speed. The model is based on three explanatory variables pressure, temperature and air-fuel ratio coefficient. The created model sl(p,t,fi) is used then for multi-variable regression, Lasso regression and support vector regression.

Comment: What is the purpose of your study? What statistic of first dataset do you want to use for your simulation?

Comment: The data set contain 669 samples and it describes the laminar flame speed by using three variables: pressure, temperature and equivalence ratio. I have to extend it by few thousands according to the statistical significance.

Comment: Why not just shift the first set of numbers by a constant?

Comment: The original data set with 669 variables contains 12 different combinations of temperature and pressure(some cases contain just 9 data samples). I simulate every each combination with additional 500 hundred simulated according to the statistical significance. I still don't know how to answer on my question.

Comment: @boplight - what you can (and maybe should) do is use a Neural network to fit the data (textbook for combustion), then uniformly randomly sample in your domain, and use the NN to predict the values.  Then I would look at using the data-driven distributions of the original values to resample from within your much higher density domain.

Comment: Does this: "I have to extend it by few thousands according to the statistical significance." mean 'You want to extrapolate your data by a small fractional amount beyond the observed data range?'

Comment: @Carl Exactly. My idea is to write equations which are used in the simulation and describe the process. I don't have more ideas.

Comment: One more thing. You need to ask an actual question. For example, "How do I test for modelling error in the second data set?" or whatever. When you do that, I will vote to reopen, however, you are going to need to put in more physical information as right now, I cannot fathom the physics of what you are doing, so I cannot help answer whatever question you are about to ask.